# Is there a way to not erase the documents directory when uninstalling the app?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, ipad, air

I'm developing an AIR app for iPad, and I found that when I uninstall the app, the documents directory data gets erased, is there a way to keep this data even when I delete the app or this behavior is regulated by iOS and there is nothing I can do about it?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cant

From The [iOS Environment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html)

`For security reasons, iOS places each app (including its preferences and data) in a sandbox at install time. A sandbox is a set of fine-grained controls that limit the app’s access to files, preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on. As part of the sandboxing process, the system installs each app in its own sandbox directory, which acts as the home for the app and its data.`

So you delete the application all the content regarding that particular app gets deleted.

Answer (score 2):

as soon app get uninstalled the document directory folder also get deleted with that. Although you will not able to access that folder from other apps so there is no need to keep that.